# Search multiple table fields with one string, broken apart (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I have a simple search feature that will search a table for a hit. Basically the one flaw of this search is that it tries to match exactly the string. I want it to take a string of say "large red bird" and search "large", "red" and "bird" separately against the table. here's my search query...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files
         WHERE (tags LIKE '%$search_ar%' OR
         name LIKE '%$search_ar%' OR
         company LIKE '%$search_ar%' OR
         brand LIKE '%$search_ar%')
         $str_thera $str_global $str_branded $str_medium $str_files");
```

any Ideas? thanks

**Edit**
OK here's my updated query but it doesnt return anything.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files
           WHERE MATCH(tags, name, company, brand)
           AGAINST ('$seach_ar' IN boolean MODE)");
```

Comment: Take a look at fulltext searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fulltext search will indeed help, given you do have a lot of data to search by. A good reference for the full text can be found here: http://forge.mysql.com/w/images/c/c5/Fulltext.pdf

The reason I say a lot of data, or a fair amount, is that if the search results yields above a certain percentage of returned rows to total rows, nothing is returned.

---

If you want to continue using the `LIKE` method, you can. You just have to seperate the words (`explode`) and the join them in the sql query using AND:

```
...(tags LIKE '%$search_ar[0]%' AND tags LIKE '%$search_ar[1]%') OR ....
```

In a fashion like that. This method can get overly complicated especially if say, you want to return matches which has any of the words and not all of them. So yea, it will take some customization to do and to automate, but it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If, for whatever reason, you can't use full text searching (nice idea, Nick and Brad, but only MyISAM supports it, and from what I hear, it's not really all that good), it's not too hard to rig up basic searching with `explode()` and `implode()`:

```
$search_arr = explode(' ',$search_str);
$search_str = implode('%',$search_arr);
//query where fields like $search_arr
```

Or:

```
$search_arr = explode(' ', $search_str);
   $sql = 'select * from files where ';
   foreach($search_arr = $term){
   $sql .= "tags like '%{$term}%' or " //fill in rest of fields
}
```

As a side note: If you plan on growing your searching and can't use MySQL's full text search, I recommend checking out one of the search servers, such as Solr or Lucene.

Comment: OK here's my updated query but it doesnt return anything.... $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE MATCH(tags, name, company, brand) AGAINST ('$seach_ar' IN boolean MODE)");

Comment: @Greg, if the query returns more then 50% of the rows in the database, it will not return anything. Which is why if you have a small database, fulltext is not good. If you are doing testing, it is also hard, but just add a bunch of fake rows to help you along.  @shauna, yea. That is how I tend to do it. I like my InnoDB.

Comment: @Brad - Makes two of us. What's up with that, anyway? It's like they said, "if you want searching, you can't have key constraints, and if you want constraints, you can't have search." Why don't they just implement search on InnoDB?